# ORMLite on Android: cannot get table entries

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite

I am trying to use ORMLite on Android. I use an existing SQLite database that I copy from the assets folder in the external storage space of the phone. This part works correctly.

I also managed to create a DAO for one of the tables (it is able to find the table, I am sure of it) but when I try getting the entries by using queryForAll on the DAO, I always get 0 items. I used the count method and I also get a value of 0, but this table has items.

How is it possible?

My table name is "info" and I use this DAO:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName="info")
public class Info {
@DatabaseField
private String version;

@DatabaseField
private String kanjidic2Version;

@DatabaseField
private String kanjiVGVersion;

/**
 * Gets the version.
 * @return the version.
 */
public String getVersion(){
    return this.version;
}

/**
 * Gets the KanjiDic2 version
 * @return the version.
 */
public String getKanjidic2Version(){
    return this.kanjidic2Version;
}

/**
 * Gets the KanjiVG version.
 * @return the version.
 */
public String getKanjiVGVersion(){
    return this.kanjiVGVersion;
}
```

I have 1 row in the info table but it looks like the app is not able to get it. Here is the code I use to get it:

```
public class InfoRepository {
Dao<Info, String> infoDao;

public InfoRepository(DBHelper helper){
    try{
        this.infoDao = helper.getInfoDao();
    }catch(SQLException e){
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), e.getMessage());
    }
}

/**
 * Gets all the info.
 * @return all the info.
 */
public List<Info> getAll(){
    List<Info> infos = new ArrayList<>();
    try{
        long count = this.infoDao.countOf();
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Info entry count: " +count);
        infos.addAll(this.infoDao.queryForAll());
    }catch(SQLException e){
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), e.getMessage());
    }
    return infos;
}
}
```

**Edit: Here is the code of DBHelper:**

```
public class DBHelper extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper {
private final static String DB_NAME = "kanjidb.db";
private final static int DB_VERSION = 1;

private String dataDir;
private AssetManager assetManager;

private Dao<Info, String> infoDao = null;

public DBHelper(Context context){
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    this.init(context);
}

public DBHelper(Context context, String databaseName, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int databaseVersion) {
    super(context, databaseName, factory, databaseVersion);
    this.init(context);
}

public DBHelper(Context context, String databaseName, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int databaseVersion, int configFileId) {
    super(context, databaseName, factory, databaseVersion, configFileId);
    this.init(context);
}

public DBHelper(Context context, String databaseName, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int databaseVersion, File configFile) {
    super(context, databaseName, factory, databaseVersion, configFile);
    this.init(context);
}

public DBHelper(Context context, String databaseName, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int databaseVersion, InputStream stream) {
    super(context, databaseName, factory, databaseVersion, stream);
    this.init(context);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, ConnectionSource connectionSource) {
    try {
        Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Creating database...");
        //TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, Entry.class);
        TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, Info.class);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, ConnectionSource connectionSource, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    try{
        if(oldVersion < 2){
            Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Updating database...");

            // Example
            // "test" column has been added in version 2
            this.infoDao.executeRaw("ALTER TABLE 'info' ADD COLUMN test INTEGER;");
        }
    }catch(SQLException e){
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public synchronized void close(){
    super.close();
    this.infoDao = null;
}

/**
 * Gets the info DAO
 * @return the info DAO.
 * @throws SQLException in case of issue.
 */
public Dao<Info, String> getInfoDao() throws SQLException {
    if(null == this.infoDao){
        this.infoDao = getDao(Info.class);
    }

    return this.infoDao;
}

/**
 * Initializes this object.
 * @param context as the given context.
 */
private void init(Context context){
    this.dataDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator +"ORMLiteTest";
    this.assetManager = context.getAssets();

    String filePath = this.dataDir +File.separator + DB_NAME;

    if(!this.exists(filePath)){
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "-- Database not found --");
        getWritableDatabase();
        try {
            this.copyDatabaseFromAssets(filePath);
        }catch(IOException e){
            Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Gets an indication whether the given database exists.
 * @param dbPath as the given database path.
 * @return true if it exists; otherwise false.
 */
boolean exists(String dbPath){
    if(null == dbPath){
        throw new NullPointerException("dbPath");
    }

    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "checking if this DB exists: " +dbPath);
    File dbFile = new File(dbPath);
    return dbFile.exists();
}

/**
 * Copies the database from the assets folder.
 * @param dbPath as the given database path.
 * @throws IOException in case of database file not found.
 */
private void copyDatabaseFromAssets(String dbPath) throws IOException{
    InputStream input = this.assetManager.open(DB_NAME);
    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(dbPath);
    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Creating database in: " +dbPath);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while((length = input.read(buffer)) > 0){
        output.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    output.flush();
    output.close();
    input.close();
}
}
```

Does anyone has any idea?

Thank you!

Comment: I think yuo need to give us more code. Can we see the code for your class DBHelper?

Comment: Sure! I edited the post.

Comment: Not sure how u init ur dbhelper class but maybe try generate a dbhelper class inside ur Inforepository using a constructor and then test to see if it will queryforall successfully.